# Checking the file modification date before downloading from Google Drive

Tags: r, google-drive-api

The files are located in my location (this is not a valid link)

```
"https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1-wXe9h97H2_cKTcdHtFBGXMdTdjsgskdjhgtAq"
```

I'm reading a list of csv files

```
folder <- drive_get(as_id(folder_url))
csv_files <- drive_ls(folder, type = "csv")
csv_files
```

My attempt to read the file's modification date returns an error

```
file.mtime(as_id(csv_files [1, ]))
```

The goal is to compare modification dates with the file located on the local disk and download the file only if it is newer in the network location

Comment: Most (all?) of R's `file.*` functions work on the local filesystem. The docs for the `googledrive` package suggest that the mod-time is available in the return value of `drive_ls` (e.g., `drive_ls(orderBy = "folder,modifiedTime desc,name" )` sorts by it), does `csv_files` not show it for you? (I don't have a google drive so I cannot test, so I don't know what `csv_files` looks like, much less `as_id(csv_files)`.)

Comment: Any chance you can give me a fully working sample showing your issue.   My knowledge of r us very limited but I know this API I have an idea what the problem could be

Comment: ```as_datetime (csv_files$drive_resource [1][[1]]$modifiedTime)``` it works and gives the file modification time and date